# How to disable test fixtures when no tests are running in the current namespace?

Tags: clojure, clojure.test, clojure-testing

I have seen many clojure projects that disable integration tests by default by adding this setting to `project.clj`:

```
:test-selectors {:default (complement :integration)
                 :integration :integration}
```

But, if a namespace contains only integration tests, the fixtures in it still run when I run `lein test`!

For example if I run `lein new app test` and make the contents of `core_test.clj` this:

```
(defn fixture [f]
  (println "Expensive setup fixture is running")
  (f))
(use-fixtures :once fixture)

(deftest ^:integration a-test
  (println "integration test running"))
```

Then when I run `lein test` I see the fixture running even though no tests are run.

What is the correct way to handle this in clojure?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way to accomplish not running the expensive computation is to take advantage of the fact that even though the `:once` fixtures will run regardless of whether there are tests to run in the ns or not, the `:each` fixtures will only run on each actually-running test.

Instead of doing the actual computation (or acquiring resources like a db connection, or doing whatever side-effects) in the `:once` fixture, we only do it in the first (we want to do it only once!) `:each` fixture, for example doing as following:

```
(def run-fixture? (atom true))

(defn enable-fixture [f]
  (println "enabling expensive fixture...")
  (try
    (f)
    (finally (reset! run-fixture? true))))

(defn expensive-fixture [f]
  (if @run-fixture?
    (do
      (println "doing expensive computation and acquiring resources...")
      (reset! run-fixture? false))
    (println "yay, expensive thing is done!"))
  (f))

(use-fixtures :once enable-fixture)
(use-fixtures :each expensive-fixture)

(deftest ^:integration integration-test
  (println "first integration test"))

(deftest ^:integration second-integration-test
  (println "second integration test"))
```

The output of `lein test` will be as following (notice how the `enable-fixture` has run but not the expensive `expensive-fixture`):

```
› lein test

lein test fixture.core-test
enabling expensive fixture...

Ran 0 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

When running `lein test :integration`, the `expensive-fixture` will run exactly once:

```
› lein test :integration

lein test fixture.core-test
enabling expensive fixture...
doing expensive computation and acquiring resources...
first integration test
yay, expensive thing is done!
second integration test

Ran 2 tests containing 0 assertions.
0 failures, 0 errors.
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the fixture is running regardless of whether the tests run. Then, you could put the fixture functionality into the test itself to "manually" control that setup/teardown. Pseudocode:

```
(defn run-all-tests []
  (do-test-1)
  ...
  (do-test-N))

(deftest ^:slow mytest
  (do-setup)
  (run-all-tests)
  (do-teardown))
```